# Сравнить строки вида mm:ss.ms в json

Tags: javascript, json, сортировка, время

Есть объект json и в нем есть строки:

> ```
> {
>             "id": "1",
>             "time": "01:44.6"
> },
> {
>             "id": "2",
>             "time": "01:45.9"
> },
> {
>             "id": "3",
>             "time": "00:58.9"
> }
> ```

Где **time** - это строка вида `минуты:секунды.миллисекунды` **(mm:ss.ms)**.

**Как отсортировать объекты в `json` по `time`?**

*ps.Date.parse() -не работает и (я думаю) это потому , что неверный формат данных , но данные в Json менять нельзя , а преобразовать я не знаю как.*

Comment: json - это строка. Что такое объект json?

Comment: Я не очень сильный в программировании, но разве выражение помещенное в { } не объект ? Плюс , если говорить строго , то в js разве не всё объекты ??( Даже обычная строка это объект )

Comment: Объект - да, json - нет. json - это нотация сериализованных данных. `x={};` - js объект. `JSON.stringify(x)`, `'{"a": 42}'` - json.

Comment: https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-json-c798d2723107 - может поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, так?

```js
const data = [
  {
              "id": "1",
              "time": "01:44.6"
  },
  {
              "id": "2",
              "time": "01:45.9"
  },
  {
              "id": "3",
              "time": "00:58.9"
  }
];

data.sort(
  (a, b) => {
    const [mm1, ss1, ms1] = a.time.split(/[:.]/).map(num => Number(num));
    const [mm2, ss2, ms2] = b.time.split(/[:.]/).map(num => Number(num));

    return mm1 - mm2 || ss1 - ss2 || ms1 - ms2;
  }
);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: спасибо...я думал в принципе тоже самое , просто убрать **: .** и потом сравнить